# How many nodes can be effectively stored inside of Neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j

How many nodes can be effectively stored inside of the Neo4j database?
Are there any limitations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Neo4j 3.0, there are no limits.

"Dynamic pointer compression expands Neo4j’s available address space as needed, making it possible to store graphs of any size. That’s right: no more 34 billion node limits!" [Neo4j documentation](https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-3-0-massive-scale-developer-productivity/#capabilities-data-size)

Comment: This is only valid for Neo4j Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 7):

The limitation is currently 2^35, so approximately 34 billion nodes.

See [the documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/capabilities-capacity.html#capabilities-data-size).